# PHP How to get random element from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have the following array:

```
$var = array( 
"green" => array("one", "two"), 
"red" => array("three", "four"),
"yellow" => array("five", "six")
);
```

What code would I need to write to generate a random output of any of the numbers?

I've tried the following, which will give me either "one", "three" or "five".

```
$section = array_rand($var);
echo $var[$section][0];
```

However I can't seem to randomise the key, so it will randomly choose a colour, and then randomly choose a number within that colour. I'm obviously having a dim moment. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`The short way to get random element` in that case:

```
$var = array( 
"green" => array("one", "two"), 
"red" => array("three", "four"),
"yellow" => array("five", "six")
);

$section = array_rand($var); //here yoy get random first of array(green or red or yellow)
echo $var[$section][array_rand($var[$section])]; //here you get random element of this array
```

Comment: Thanks for this, nicely explained as well.

Comment: Hope it will be usefull)

Answer (score 8):

`array_rand()` will randomize the complete array. This means it will

- consume much entropy
- Use quite a lot of CPU horsepower, if the array is large
- create a copy of the array, using up RAM.

So I prefer

```
function getrandomelement($array) {
  $pos=rand(0,sizeof($array)-1);
  $res=$array[$pos];
  if (is_array($res)) return getrandomelement($res);
  else return $res;
}
```

and ofcourse

```
echo getrandomelement($var);
```

**EDIT**

In case this is not clear, the above function will work for any dimension, even with different sizes (non-square/cube).

Comment: Wonderful solution! (Love the recursivity.)

Comment: This doesn't work with the above array, it only works when it has keys. How could this be adapted to work with values for keys as well?

Comment: Adaption is `$res=$array[array_keys[$pos]];` inside the function

Comment: I couldn't get the above to work, as when I tried `$res=$array[array_keys($pos)]` I got an error relating to $pos being an integer and not an array. However I've adapted what I was doing a little and so it has still been useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Whitenoise It should be `array_keys($array)[$pos]`